# How to access a Set after asynchronous calls are complete

Tags: angular, typescript, asynchronous, callback

Using this code, I can properly add to the 'MaterialCollectionSet'

```
let MaterialCollectionSet: Set<string> = new Set();

for(let data of SDE_REACTIONDATA) {

  this.ESI.ReturnsType_AtId(data.materialTypeID).subscribe((MaterialData) => {

    MaterialCollectionSet.add(MaterialData.name);

});
```

However, trying to run *this* code

```
let MaterialCollectionSet: Set<string> = new Set();

for(let data of SDE_REACTIONDATA) {

  this.ESI.ReturnsType_AtId(data.materialTypeID).subscribe((MaterialData) => {

      MaterialCollectionSet.add(MaterialData.name);

}); 

console.log(MaterialCollectionSet);
```

Will log an empty Set.

I understand this is due to asynchronous calls happening *after* the console.log is called outside the for-of loop.

My question is how to actually use the Set once the for-of loop has completed populating it?

Comment: https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/merge: merge all the observables into a single one, subscribe to this unique observable to add every event emitted to the set, and pass a completion callback when subscribing to log the complete set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `forkJoin` to await all requests

```
const requests$ = SDE_REACTIONDATA.map(data => this.ESI.ReturnsType_AtId(data.materialTypeID));

let MaterialCollectionSet: Set<string> = new Set();

forkJoin(requests$).subscribe(responses => {
  // Now you can access the `responses`;
  MaterialCollectionSet.add(responses.map(MaterialData => MaterialData.name));
})
```

Or as @JB Nizet suggested:

```
const requests$ = SDE_REACTIONDATA.map(data => this.ESI.ReturnsType_AtId(data.materialTypeID));

let MaterialCollectionSet: Set<string> = new Set();

merge(requests$).subscribe(
  MaterialData => MaterialCollectionSet.add(MaterialData.name),
  null, // error handler
  () => console.log(MaterialCollectionSet) // complete
)
```

The righht solution depends on what do you need.

Comment: Thank you for the response! The multi-parameter '.subscribe' executes in order? I have not worked with that syntax before. Do all subscribes have a parameter for a completion callback? Or is it just merge-style subscribes.

Comment: `forkJoin` is like Promise.all, emit after all observables complete.
`merge` emit on each observables emit. If order matter take a look at `concat `.
every subscribe [has](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/subscribe.html) (next, error, complete) callbacks.